# How to start Robocopy from a Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to transfer user data in the C:\ drive from a networked computer to the C:\ drive on the local computer. So I need to exclude all the System Folders and Hidden Folders.

This is what I have for my powershell script.

```
$asset = Read-Host "What is the Asset Number?"
$useraiu = Read-Host "What is the user's AIU?"

$source = "\\$asset\C$\"
$dest = "C:\Temp\Dest"

$excludedFolders = '_SMSTaskSequence','inetpub','Program Files','Program Files (x86)','Swsetup','Users','Windows','CCM','Notes'

$myFolders = Get-ChildItem  -Path "\\$asset\C$\" -Directory | where { $_ -notin $excludedFolders }

$myFolders | foreach { robocopy $_  $dest /S /Z /MT /XJD /XA:SH /log+:"\\server\path\path\%asset%-to-%computername%-Transfer-Log.log" /NP /FP /V /TEE}

Read-Host "Press ENTER to quit"
```

When I do a `Write-Output $myFolders` it displays the correct directories that I want to copy.

Looks like the robocopy function is using the local C:\ path as the source. The source should be `\\$asset\C$\` the folders listed in `$myFolders`

Example.  If this folder is on the old computer `\\computername\C$\Userfolder-Pictures` Use Robocopy to copy that folder to `C:\Userfolder-Pictures` on the local computer

I get this output from Robocopy after I run the script.

```
 Log File : \\server\path\path\%asset%-to-%computername%-Transfer-Log.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon Jun 08 11:11:28 2015

   Source : C:\WINDOWS\system32\Temp\
     Dest : C:\Temp\Dest\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /V /FP /TEE /S /COPY:DAT /Z /NP /XJD /XA:SH /MT:8 /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2015/06/08 11:11:28 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory C:\WINDOWS\system32\Temp\
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: trailing slashes I have found are not welcome on the source or path.

Comment: Thats not even the issue. The source path listed is completely wrong from what should or what I expected to be there.

Comment: What do you expect to be there? Did you verify that `$asset` isn't null or empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` will give you the full network path to the folders in an array of strings.  Your `foreach` loop through `$myFolders` is currently looping through an array of `DirectoryInfo` objects instead.

```
$myFolders = Get-ChildItem  -Path "\\$asset\C$\" -Directory | where { $_ -notin $excludedFolders } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Or, if you plan on using information from `$myFolders` other than `FullName`, you could change this line to use `$_.FullName`.

```
$myFolders | foreach { robocopy $_.FullName  $dest /S /Z /MT /XJD /XA:SH /log+:"\\server\path\path\%asset%-to-%computername%-Transfer-Log.log" /NP /FP /V /TEE}
```

Comment: Thanks!  `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`  is working for me.

Comment: Actually I have a question. The source for the robocopy is working correctly, but I would like the destination to be the same as the source but local to C:\ drive. Example Source: `\\computername\Temp-Pictures` then the destination is `C:\Temp-Pictures`.  Currently this isn't working that way. Could you help out with that?

Comment: Oh I gotcha.  Does `C:\Temp-Pictures` (for example) always exist on the local, or do we need to create it every time?

Comment: There may be a more "PowerShell" way of doing this, but the regex is simple.
`$p = "\\SomeServer01\c$\path\to\something\"`
`$local = $p -replace "\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\c\$","C:"`

Comment: Usually no the local path would not exist. Is there a way to get a variable like $dest that comes from the $myFolders to use with the Robocopy command. Example from the code above $myFolders get a list of directories from a networked computer `\\computername\Temp-pictures` and other folders. I want to copy that to the same location on the local computer `C:\Temp-Pictures` and the same for any other folder found by the $myFolders